# New to python django, how to auto populate a field?

Tags: python, django

I have two fields in my model.py one has multi choice drop down and one that is empty. What I would like to have is that if the user select "Gas" from the menu for type, I would like the amount field to get auto populated with distance * 2
Can I do that?

```
CHOICE = (
    ('Meal', 'Meal'),
    ('Gas', 'Gas'),
    )
type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICE)
distance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
amount = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to do this in the form itself?

Comment: good question @AKS can I do it from the model admin?

Comment: actually it won't matter where I do it. the question is can I do it? and how to do it in the form itself?

Comment: if you use the right tool for the job, it's a two liner and that tool is javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [django-observer](https://github.com/lambdalisue/django-observer) app for this. Although there are cleaner Javascript approaches, you can make the automation totally depend on Django.

First, modify the amount field as:

```
amount = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```

since it won't take any values when the model object is initially saved to the database. Then the rest of the code will look something like:

```
from observer.decorators import watch

def compute_amount(sender, obj, attr):
     if obj.type == 'Gas':
          obj.amount = obj.distance * 2 
          obj.save()

@watch('type', compute_amount, call_on_created=True) 
class FuelConsumption(models.Model):
     CHOICE = (
              ('Meal', 'Meal'),
              ('Gas', 'Gas'),
              )
     type = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICE)
     distance = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     amount = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
```